# How to make user's turn end when certain type of card is randomly generated? If-else statement not working

Tags: python

I'm fairly new at coding and I'm making a game in which the user plays a random card drawing game against the computer. The goal is to reach 50 points first and you reach that by drawing the cards.

For example, a 2 of Clubs should have a value of 2 and a King of Hearts should have a value of 13. The user and computer take turns drawing cards and you may continue your turn as long as you want and accumulate points, unless you draw any type of Ace or Jack, in which you lose all points for that turn and your turn ends.

In my code, I'm not sure why the user doesn't lose points and their turn doesn't end when they draw an Ace or Jack, even though there's a section of code that specifically includes an if-else statement acknowledging it. Can anyone help me?

## Btw, this is as minimal as I can make the code so that you can understand how it works at its basics, while making sure that the if-else statement in question still has the same steps leading up to it.

```
# Useful Definitions
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
user_turn_score = 0
computer_turn_score = 0
type = "user"
import random

class Card:
    suits = {'c': '♣','h': '♥','s': '♠','d': '♦'}
    faces = {
        1: 'Ace',
        11: 'Jack',
        12: 'Queen',
        13: 'King'
    }
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    def __repr__(self):
        face = self.faces.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return f'{face}{self.suits[self.suit]}'
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self.rank + other
        return self.rank + other.rank
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other + self.rank
        return self.rank + other.rank
        
sorted_deck = [Card(n, s) for s in Card.suits for n in range(1, 14)]
    
if type == "user":
    user_turn_score = 0
    random_drawn_card = random.choice(sorted_deck)
    print("Your card: " + str(random_drawn_card))
    sorted_deck.remove(random_drawn_card)
    if random_drawn_card == "Ace♣" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♥" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♦" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♠" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♣" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♥" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♦" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♠":
        user_turn_score = 0
        print("You drew an Ace or a Jack. You will not gain any points this turn.")
        type = "computer"
    else:
        value = random_drawn_card.rank
        user_turn_score = user_turn_score + value
        user_score = user_score + user_turn_score
        print("Your points this round: " + str(user_turn_score))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction. Just below `sorted_deck.remove(random_drawn_card)` I added

```
print(random_drawn_card == str(random_drawn_card))

# False
```

In other words, the way it's displayed is not the same as what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "foo"

instance = MyClass()
print(instance == "foo") # False
print(str(instance) == "foo") # True
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue Seemed to be you using an else statement, I changed it to an elif doing the opposite conditions of the other if statement for the aces and stuff. I also am forcing the card to be an ace for debugging purpose since it never seemed to drawn a loosing card, so you may want to re-work you card picking system, I added a couple of print lines for it to print the type and score, you now loose points when you draw a loosing card hope this helps!

```
# Useful Definitions
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
user_turn_score = 0
computer_turn_score = 0
type = "user"
import random

class Card:
    suits = {'c': '♣','h': '♥','s': '♠','d': '♦'}
    faces = {
        1: 'Ace',
        11: 'Jack',
        12: 'Queen',
        13: 'King'
    }
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    def __repr__(self):
        face = self.faces.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return f'{face}{self.suits[self.suit]}'
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self.rank + other
        return self.rank + other.rank
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other + self.rank
        return self.rank + other.rank
        
sorted_deck = [Card(n, s) for s in Card.suits for n in range(1, 14)]

    
if type == "user":
    user_turn_score = 0
    random_drawn_card = random.choice(sorted_deck)
    print("Your card: " + str(random_drawn_card))
    sorted_deck.remove(random_drawn_card)
    random_drawn_card = "Ace♣" # Just Forcing it to be an ace
    if random_drawn_card == "Ace♣" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♥" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♦" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♠" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♣" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♥" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♦" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♠":
        user_turn_score -= 1 # Now Subtracts points
        print("You drew an Ace or a Jack. You will not gain any points this turn.")
        type = "computer"
        print(type) # Debugging
        print(user_turn_score) # Debugging
    elif random_drawn_card != "Ace♣" or random_drawn_card != "Ace♥" or random_drawn_card != "Ace♦" or random_drawn_card != "Ace♠" or random_drawn_card != "Jack♣" or random_drawn_card != "Jack♥" or random_drawn_card != "Jack♦" or random_drawn_card != "Jack♠":
        value = random_drawn_card.rank
        user_turn_score = user_turn_score + value
        user_score = user_score + user_turn_score
        print("Your points this round: " + str(user_turn_score))
```